# I am trying to create e dynamic table where data will be fetched and I can edit any value I want

Tags: php, mysql

I can fetch the data but the submit button is not working.
 I am confused with the update query and storing data in array.
Here is the code for fetching and showing data in table.

```
     `<?php
           while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
               <tr>
               <td align="center">
               <?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?>
               </td>
               <td align="center">  
               <input name="name[]" type="text" id="name" value="<?=$rows['name']; ?>">
               </td>
               <td align="center">
               <input name="lastname[]" type="text" id="lastname" value="<? =$rows['lastname']; ?>">
               </td>
               <td align="center">
               <input name="email[]" type="text" id="email" value="<?=$rows['email']; ?>">
               </td>
               </tr>
```

`

Here is the code for submit button

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $_POST["Submit"] != ""){
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $sql2="UPDATE test_mysql SET name='".$_POST["name"][$i]."',lastname='".$_POST["lastname"][$i]."', email='".$_POST["email"][$i]."' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
            $result1=mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
        }
header("Location: update-multiple-2.php");
```

}

Comment: my first debugging test would be to `echo $sql2;` see if it looks right

Comment: Error: undefined variable. Pretty sure something wrong with update query or data storing. I am stuck with the update query for almost 6 hours. Couldn't figure out what's wrong. Thanks for your help. @nogad

Comment: have you tested that you actually get inside that condition ?

Comment: Two  error shows continuously(Notice: Use of undefined constant sql2  and Notice: Undefined variable: test_mysql ). Yes, script gets inside the loop and the for loop works fine. @nogad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you handle POST after outputting form (to set variable `$id`) and variable `$test_mysql` is set to existing table in your database and all columns exists and you are only one who can add or remove row (because it will change the `$id` variable) then it should work.

Maybe this could help:

```
if(!$result1=mysqli_query($con, $sql2)){
    echo 'Error: '.mysqli_error();
}
```

You need to debug it somehow:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $_POST["Submit"] != ""){
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $error = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $sql2="UPDATE $test_mysql SET name='".$_POST["name"][$i]."',lastname='".$_POST["lastname"][$i]."', email='".$_POST["email"][$i]."' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
        if(mysqli_query($con, $sql2) === FALSE){
            $error .= 'SQL query failed, SQL: '.$sql2.', Error: '.mysqli_error() . "\n";        
        }
    }

    if(!$error){
        header("Location: update-multiple-2.php");
    }else{
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe because of location header

Comment: follow error messages, print value of `$count`, `$id`, `$sql2` to check if they are alright (after they are set), variable `$result` must be set to get correct `$count`, and if you redirect page you cant see output so comment header location for debugging